# HTML form passing values to web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I am currently working on a page where a user would select all the appropriate fields in a search form (html) which would than pass the values to the web2py query.

I am having an issue with writing this query? I am wondering how to actually pass the values from HTML form to the web2py query to be run against the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit a form to web2py (via GET or POST), all the form variables will be available in `request.vars` (for more on this, see the book sections on [Dispatching](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04#Dispatching) and the [`request` object](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04#request) as well as the chapter on [forms](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07)).

So, you could do something like:

```
def search():
    rows = None
    if request.vars:
        query = reduce(lambda a, b: (a & b),
            (db.mytable[var] == request.vars[var] for var in request.vars))
        rows = db(query).select()
    return dict(rows=rows)
```

Note, the `reduce()` with the generator expression is equivalent to writing a query like this:

```
(db.mytable.field1 == request.vars.field1) & \
(db.mytable.field2 == request.vars.field2) & \
...
(db.mytable.fieldN == request.vars.fieldN)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, however I am still a bit confused as to what you've done there..

what does query = reduce(lambda a, b: (a & b) mean?

Comment: It just takes a list of queries and joins them with the `&` logical operator. `reduce` is a Python function, so you can probably find online resources explaining its use. That bit of code is not web2py specific -- just a shortcut way of creating the query without having to write it all out manually (as shown in the last section of code).