# Web2Py Error

Tags: web2py

I am getting an error when I try to run the code for Web2Py.

Basically we have to write a function that would query the database and show the flights available.

The function is defined as below:

```
def searchFlights():
    return dict()

def show():
    receivedFlights = request.vars.originCity+','+request.vars.destCity+','+request.vars.type+','+request.vars.deptDate+','+request.vars.arrivalDate+','+request.vars.vlassType+','+request.vars.noOfAdults+','+request.vars.noOfChildren+','+request.vars.noOfInfants
    return dict(txt1=recievedflights, flights=db().select(db.Flight.request.originCity+','+request.vars.destCity+','+request.vars.type+','+request.vars.deptDate+','+request.vars.arrivalDate+','+request.vars.classType+','+request.vars.noOfAdults+','+request.vars.noOfChildren+','+request.vars.noOfInfants))
```

The error we are getting right now is:

```
  **File "K:/wdd-softw/web2py/applications/Assignment/controllers/default.py", line 106, in show
    receivedFlights = request.vars.originCity+','+request.vars.destCity+','+request.vars.type+','+request.vars.deptDate+','+request.vars.arrivalDate+','+request.vars.vlassType+','+request.vars.noOfAdults+','+request.vars.noOfChildren+','+request.vars.noOfInfants
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'**

Comment: Some of the request.vars variable is not available = None ?

Comment: You can use request.vars.get("originalCity","") which returns empty string when parameter is not available ...

Comment: Hi David,

I realised I had a few issues with the code which was the variable names that were being pulled out of the form.. they were almost all incorrect. I've now fixed them however I am still getting an error stating:
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and  'NoneType' objects...

Comment: you should print each request.vars variable to console to see, which is missing in request ... or use syntax with .get to safely return default value when variable is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that when the page with the form first loads, nothing has been submitted, so `request.vars` is empty and therefore each `request.vars.some_var` returns None. Instead, you could do something like this:

```
receivedFlights = ', '.join(request.vars.values()) if request.vars else 'Empty'
```

You'll have the same problem with your database select -- you should only run the query when request.vars exists. Furthermore, your query is incorrect -- you cannot simply concatenate all the values into a single string and put that in the `select()`. I suggest you read the chapter on the [DAL](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06) for proper query syntax. It should look more like:

```
db((db.Flight.originCity == request.vars.originCity) &
   (db.Flight.destCity == request.vars.destCity) &
   ...).select()
```

Finally, you can simplify the query construction, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14293880/440323):

```
query = reduce(lambda a, b: (a & b),
    (db.mytable[v] == request.vars[v] for v in request.vars if v != None))
```

Comment: Hi Anthony,

Thanks for your reply.. I am using a custom HTML form so would i still need to use the FORM or SQLFORM helpers, I am not sure how to actually use those....

Just to debug my assignment and to check if the flights are being being displayed.. I wrote another query which shows all the flights in the database but this is a direct query which isn't going through any views.. the function is:


    def displayFlights():
        showFlights = flights=db().select(db.Flight.ALL)
        return dict(showFlights=showFlights)

Comment: I still can't seem to get my head around as to how the function is pulling the data from the HTML form and querying the database..

Comment: Hey Anthony, I've created a database query to return the flights in the database but its returning an empty page; I don't know what the return line should be.


def displayFlights():
    db((db.Flight.DepartureLocation == request.vars.DepartureLocation)&
       (db.Flight.ArrivalLocation == request.vars.ArrivalLocation)&
       (db.Flight.DepartureDate == request.vars.DepartureDate)&
       (db.Flight.ArrivalDate == request.vars.DepartureDate)).select()
    return dict()

Comment: Hi Anthony,

I've gotten it to show all the flights now, however its showing the all the flights that are in the database and not filtering it according to what the user has select... the query that I am using right is the a similar...

Comment: When constructing queries, you must use `==` rather than `is`.

Answer (score 0):

Use  ...+str(request.vars.noOfAdults)+... to convert number field to string.